# Escaping Dot in Azure Search Query

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

According to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/search/query-lucene-syntax)
in Azure Search i am aware that the following special characters + - & | ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ / can be escaped in the search string query by using backslash (\).

However i tried to escape character dot using backslash but it doesnt work.

Normally having dot at the end of the search string query is treated as stop word therefore it doesnt get included when the query executes unless we find a way to escape it. Therefore is there a way to escape dot in the search query so that we can somehow ensure that the character gets included when query executes.

Comment: Can you provide a code sample with what you had, what you are trying to do (how you're trying to escape now), and the error message that results?

Comment: Thank you for your response Heath. I have figured out to fix this via switching to fuzzy search in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was switching to fuzzy search in a scenario like this and i got the result as expected